# How to setup subversion (and which - e.g. subcliplse / subversive) for android / java eclipse on LAN [without internet connection / (url/uri)]

Tags: java, android, eclipse, svn

I didn't knew what is subversion.

When came to know it's importance for more than one developer. The question arose.

How to set it up for use.

We are developing in Eclipse for Android.  Details of installation:

```
Android DDMS    22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508
Android Developer Tools 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826
Android Development Tools   22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508
Android Hierarchy Viewer    22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508
Android Native Development Tools    22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508
Android Traceview   22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508
JavaHL 1.7.4 Win32 Binaries (Optional)  2.3.0.I20120316-1700
Native JavaHL 1.7 Implementation (Optional) 2.3.0.I20120520-1700
Subversive Revision Graph (Optional) (Incubation)   0.7.9.I20120210-1700
Subversive SVN Connectors   2.3.0.I20120520-1700
Subversive SVN Integration for the Mylyn Project (Optional) (Incubation)    0.7.9.I20110602-1700
Subversive SVN JDT Ignore Extensions (Optional) (Incubation)    0.7.9.I20111119-1700
Subversive SVN Team Provider (Incubation)   0.7.9.I20120520-1700
Subversive SVN Team Provider Localization (Optional) (Incubation)   0.7.9.I20120316-1700
Subversive SVN Team Provider Sources (Incubation)   0.7.9.I20120520-1700
SVNKit 1.7.4 Implementation (Optional)  2.3.0.I20120520-1700
Tracer for OpenGL ES    22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508
```

Eclipse for Java details of installation:

```
Eclipse Standard/SDK    2.0.2.20140224-0000
Swing Designer  1.7.0.r43x201405021531
Swing Designer Documentation    1.7.0.r43x201405030444
SWT Designer    1.7.0.r43x201405021526
SWT Designer Core   1.7.0.r43x201405021519
SWT Designer Documentation  1.7.0.r43x201405030426
SWT Designer SWT_AWT Support    1.7.0.r43x201405021546
SWT Designer XWT Support (requires Eclipse WTP/WST) 1.7.0.r43x201405021548
WindowBuilder Core  1.7.0.r43x201405021445
WindowBuilder Core Documentation    1.7.0.r43x201405021506
WindowBuilder Core UI   1.7.0.r43x201405021455
WindowBuilder GroupLayout Support   1.7.0.r43x201405021517
WindowBuilder Java Core 1.7.0.r43x201405021448
WindowBuilder XML Core (requires Eclipse WTP/WST)   1.7.0.r43x201405021458
```

I have tried my best. There is no proper help available anywhere that could explain me everything to set up SVN from scratch.

After googling a lot I came to conclusion to either use subclipse or subversive (no TortoiseSVN as it doesn't support eclipse 100%).

Again had to google a lot to get subversive plugin installed in eclipse.

After getting it installed, I started -

- trying with import project -> SVN -> Project from SVN.
- On clicking next it asks for URL.

  - We have not posted our files any where on internet.
  - We want to use subversion on LAN.
  - This led me to install iis (internet information service) in windows 7

But I could not manage to sync all my tryings.

It would be very helpful if experienced one's could write or redirect me to clear my question which are as follows

1. Am i correct about using subclipse or subversive and not tortoise svn?
2. If so, which SVN we should use for?

   1. Eclipse for Android applications
   2. Eclipse for Java applications
3. How to use that selected SVN on LAN (without posting our source code files over internet)
4. If we are supposed to use IIS on windows
5. How to get our files from IIS site to subversion management?

I have genuinely tried to find step by step information. But couldn't.
Please explain step by step.
Time will take it's own course on us.
Till than let us know the basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was new to Eclipse / Java.

*[Here is a good explanation to what is subversion control.](http://betterexplained.com/articles/a-visual-guide-to-version-control/)*

After being with eclipse for a long time i decided to go with 'subclipse' and found out this webpage that answered my question no.3.

http://grumpygeekwrites.wordpress.com/2013/10/08/the-idiots-guide-to-setting-subversion-svn-server-on-windows/

What was asked in Q.4 and Q.5 wasn't required.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse and subversion are two totally different things.

On a SVN server, you can keep any kind of file (Best practices suggest to store mostly source code but in any king of languages).

You can install Tortoise on your computer AND subclipse/subversive on Eclipse, it works fine and it allow you to store files that are not related to an Eclipse project.
With Tortoise, you will see all your sync files in your OS explorere whereas with the Eclipse plugins, you can only see it in the "Team" view.

Anyway, subversion and subclipse works for Ecplise. they are not dependant of the other plugins you use in Eclipse like Android DK.

Here is an exemple on how to create a SVN repository: http://hamrotechtips.blogspot.fr/2008/03/setup-of-local-lan-svn-server.html